# Why have European regions with strong desires for independence not been allowed to have either local parliaments or referendums?

Tags: europe, referendum, secession

Is it the fault of the government's progressiveness that regions with strong desires for independence and self-rule, such as Corsica, the Basque region, Catalonia, Bavaria, Moravia, and Sicily, have limited regional assemblies and have never been offered independence referendums?

Why is Scotland the only separatist region of Europe that has independence leaders in power and had a referendum on the question of independence?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to ask about all of them lumped together.  France has a very centralized government, while Spain and Germany are federal.  No idea what Italy does, but I'd guess it's closer to France.  Each country will have a different reason for how it manages those affairs and those will be also be due to historical reasons.  The answer would thus be pretty long.  Also the "U" in UK is there for a reason.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica italy is kind of in the middle, there are more powers to the regions than in france.

Comment: FWIW, the independentists in Corsica talk up a good game - but sadly for the French taxpayers - would be unlikely to carry an election.  https://www.lefigaro.fr/flash-actu/2008/10/01/01011-20081001FILWWW00464--des-corses-opposes-a-l-independance.php so *very strong* might be overstating the case.  I think there is more support for Corsican independence from the *general* French population.  In the old good old days, the subsidies to Corsica from the central government were classified "Secret Defense", i.e. Top Secret.

Comment: What are you calling "government progressivism" ?

Comment: And re. the special context of the [UK](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/United_Kingdom):  *A kingdom and sovereign state in Western Europe *comprising the four **countries** of England, **Scotland** and Wales in the island of Great Britain, and Northern Ireland in the island of Ireland*  I assume it's definition as an assembly of countries explains Scotland' situation wrt this Q somewhat.

Comment: Changed the title from "Should they..." (we cannot decide this here) to "Why haven't..." which is something that can be answered.

Comment: @Trilarion "been allowed" would be clearer in that title.  Did improve Q tho.

Comment: The question misstates the status quo in many instances. Some of these regions, such as Basque Spain, do have significant amounts of regional autonomy, even though they don't have independence of top level sovereign states.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica Before 2011 it wasn't uncommon to read Spanish pundits in the press saying that the government should call the game from catalan nationalists and offer them a referendum of independence since they would "chicken out", cause Catalonia would loose a ton of money. I haven't read anything like it from those expertes in a while, though.

Comment: @Rekesoft Not exactly the smartest of pundits then.  Catalonia is one of the richest, if not the richest, regions in Spain.  They would *gain* a ton of money.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica That depends how the divorce agreement would be for Catalonia. Britains also thought they would gain from Brexit by account of being richer than average. Turns out that the negative effects of splitting up are in the order of the gain, so kind of nothing is really gained in the end.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosphers4Monica My point is, when speacking about independence, you can't count on real or predicted economical gains or loses to sway proponents of Brexit, catalan or corsican independence.

Comment: Bavaria has no strong will for independence, as can be read in the answer by o.m..

Answer (score 3):

Regarding Germany:

- Bavaria **has** a regional parliament. It is one of sixteen federal states.
- The **largest** regional party, the [Christian-Social Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Social_Union_in_Bavaria), is happy to wield an [outsized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horst_Seehofer) [influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andreas_Scheuer) over federal politics through their legislators in the federal parliament.
- The autonomist [Bayernpartei](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavaria_Party) polls at about 2%.
- Recognized national minorities are the [Danes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danish_minority_of_Southern_Schleswig), [Frisians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisians), [Romani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romani_people), and [Sorbs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorbs), but not the Bavarians. There was a plebiscite for the Danes a century ago, after WWI. A generation later, Denmark and Germany agreed on a package of mutual minority protections instead of touching borders. I'm not aware of any Frisian independence movement (which might be a lack of information on my part). The Romani and Sorbs would not form viable territories.

If any of the regions wanted out, even a referendum would require federal legislation. But it would be silly for the the federal level to legislate a referendum against the wishes of the region.

Comment: Say it more clearly: Bavaria is not a region with "strong will for independence".

Comment: @Roland, I'd say Bavaria celebrates a distinct identity, more than other parts of Germany. That *could* flip towards separatism if they no longer think that they can push Federal politics around.

Comment: It should be mentioned, that it was free will of Bavaria to join German Empire, at least oficially.

Comment: There is this joke about the Bayernpartei (advocating for Bavarian independence) that if they were allowed to appear on ballots in all of Germany they would get more votes in Berlin than in Bavaria.

Answer (score 1):

**Because a leave vote of 51%/49% could start a civil war.
Politically, giving a region it's own parliament is a much safer bet.**

Brexit decided to leave the EU 52%/48%.  Several commentators pointed out that if the referendum were held again, it could flip the other direction just on who turned out that day.

Northern Ireland stayed in the UK while the rest of Ireland became an independent nation in the 1921, which started "The Troubles".  In 1998 the Good Friday Agreement seemed to have ended the Troubles, after 77 years.  The Good Friday Agreement also explicitly allows Northern Ireland to leave and rejoin Ireland with a referendum.

Germany reunified in 1990.  It's unlikely there is real political will behind splitting it up again.

Most votes are electing representatives.  It's a contentious fight, but they'll have to run again in some years, and voters usually have elections in the mean time to strengthen or weaken the party currently in power.

Stay/Leave votes are one way.  The loss is catastrophic.  If you're having a Say/Leave vote, there is obviously not a good sense of national unity.  All these things mean there's a good chance for violence.

Comment: Interesting point, wondering if it can be also valide outside the West.

Comment: If you count the USSR, then when the government collapsed all the previous states just declared independence, and Russia didn't do anything to stop them - until now :(

Comment: And what about Yugoslavia?